# call javascript function when wowslider animates

Tags: javascript, slider, cufon

I'm working on a website with the wowslider and cufon for fonts.
I have a "span" that is generated from the wowslider, with some html text inside. When the wowslider animates, it generates the html text and cufon styles this text with some font.

The problem is that the cufon script only works with the first title, but not with the rest that comes after.

This is my code:

```
<!--part of the header-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    Cufon.replace('a.fuente', {
    hover: true
    });
    Cufon.replace('p.fuente');
    Cufon.replace('h1.fuente');
    Cufon.replace('h3.fuente');
    Cufon.replace('div#wowslider-container1 div.ws-title span');
});
</script>
<!--part of the header-->
<!--slider-->
<div id="wowslider-container1">
        <div class="ws_images">
        <span><img src="img/pres1/pres1.jpg" alt="pres1" title="Proyectos y Servicios Electromecánicos" id="wows0"/></span>
        <span><img src="img/pres1/pres2.jpg" alt="pres2" title="Pruebas y Montajes" id="wows1"/></span>
        </div>
        <div class="ws_bullets"><div>
        <a href="#wows0" title="Proyectos y Servicios Electromecánicos"><img src="img/pres1/tooltips/pres1.jpg" alt="pres1"/>1</a>
        <a href="#wows1" title="Pruebas y Montajes"><img src="img/pres1/tooltips/pres2.jpg" alt="pres2"/>2</a>
        </div></div>
    </div>
<!--slider-->
```

You can see it [here](http://setservices.pe/demo).
I know that I have to modify the wowslider script, but how? where?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `Cufon.refresh();` after each wowslider animation. I've never used it myself but I would imagine they will have an event you can bind in order to achieve this.